# Comprobar errores en sistema de citas medicas php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, select

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo un sistema para citas medicas, tengo una tabla llamada slot donde se guarda la hora y el dia que atenderá el doctor.
La tabla slot guarda una hora de inicio y de final y según la duración de la cita se crean los slots o turnos disponibles para cada dia.

```
============================================
|              slot                        |
============================================
|id_slot|id_dostor|hora inicio |  dia      |
============================================
|1      |1        |10:00       |  Lunes    |
============================================
|2      |1        |10:30       |  Lunes    |
============================================
```

~
Y otra tabla llamada CITASMEDICAS la cual incluye datos del paciente y se guarda el día, fecha y el slot que corresponde a esa hora.

```
===============================================================================
|Citas Medicas                                                                 |
===============================================================================
|id_cita |id_doctor | *datos del paci*|fecha_hoy |fecha_consulta|id_slot | hora|
=============================================================================
|23      |1         |"varias columnas"|2020-02-20|  2020-08-16  |  1     |10:00|
===============================================================================
```

Para agendar una cita se elige el dia y quisera que segun el dia escogido me muestre si hay slot disponibles, es decir que no haya sido escogidos antes.
espero se me entienda, lo que quiero es que segun el dia escoguido me muestre solo los slots disponibles. lo he conseguido pero si escogo una hora el martes 08 de agosto ese horario ya no esta dispopnible pára el optro martes y esa no es la idea si no que todos los martes tener el mismo horario....

Comment: te falta una taba agenda, que se crea automaticamente cada x cantidad de tiempo, y es la que arma lo que vos llamas slots vacios para cada medico y dia en que atiende. entonces vos asignas a esa tabla el paciente.. pero ya tiene todo en blanco de entrada.. miralo como si fuera una agenda de mano.. ya todo esta previamente creado. Si lo queres hacer es mano, es mucho mas trabajoso ya que tendrias que buscar entre todas las citas donde estan los agujeros

Comment: @gbianchi Armar espacios para cada día del mes o como?

Comment: Una agenda, como las de mano. Si, espacios para todo los dias